# Ranked choices in R: result analysis

Tags: r, statistics, regression, multinomial

Please consider the following sample data set:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1968, 2, 1)
b <- c(2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1984, 2, 0)
c <- c(3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1945, 1, 0)
d <- c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1975, 3, 1)
df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))
names(df) <- c("ID", "OptionW", "OptionX", "OptionY", "OptionZ", "yearofBirth", "education", "sex")


ID OptionW OptionX OptionY OptionZ yearofBirth education sex
1       2       3       1       4        1968         2   1
2       1       2       4       3        1984         2   0
3       3       4       2       1        1945         1   0
4       1       4       3       2        1975         3   1
```

Two hundred people where asked to rank Options W to Z from 1 to 4 in their effectiveness to lower crime rates in their community. Their age, highest academic degree and sex are annotated as well.
I want to find out:

- which options are preferred by the majority of citizens?
- are there significant differences in what men or women, old or young, well or less well educated citizens believe?
- how likely is the ranking order going to change if the person is older/younger, has had more or less formal education and is male or female?

I read that a multinomial logistic regression might be the way to go, but I find it hard to adapt the examples I find to my data set. Often they allow for only one option to be chosen, making each choice (W, X Y Z) a level of one variable (Options). But in my case I have several variables (OptionW, OptionX, OptionY, OptionZ) where the ranking placement appears to be the level (1,2,3,..10). Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Which function from what package would be suitable? And are there other methods available apart from multinomial logistic regression? Could I do a cluster analysis on 200 samples?

I use R mostly for spatial analysis and am not very fluent in statistics. Hopefully you can help me here.

Comment: Maybe better suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) if it is not so much about how to write the code, but what procedure to choose?